# Curious! js links not working at the end of the file

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink

I'm curious problem linking my js files in my php webpage. First at all, I put it at the end of the file (just before closing body tag) and in local mode everything works ok. But when I upload my web to my server js files seems not linking, I have to put it in header to work it.

So that way could be important to say all my functions are in a separated file called "scripts".

It's not important trouble, but I'm concerned. Anybody could explain me?

Thanks in advance

**Edited**
Thank you @Pointy and @Jochen for your quickly answer. I tried using chrome inspector. No errors show, only not load files. This is my web structure (I don't copy complete code cause would be so extense)

```
<!Doctype html>  
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
        <!--CSS starter-->
        <link href="" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <!--CSS font-awesome-->
        <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <!--[if IE 7]>
            <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <![endif]-->

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- javascript (here links working) -->


  </head>

  <body>


<!--sections--> 
<!--/sections--> 

<!-- javascript (here not working) -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages_es.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>


 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter where you put your script. You've posted none of your code, so it's not possible to say what's causing the problem.

Comment: Clt+U, in source code click on your js file link, if it not show code ...check file path.

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia is not file path cause in local mode I can link js files from server path and works... is really strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I guess this path is wrong, try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about that cause is the same path when links are in header and works isn't it?

Comment: Try it! If it isn't working, offer us a zip-file of your website. So we are able to debug it ourselves.

Comment: No problem, always remember: Javascript dies silently ... so my expierence taught me to log (using console.log() in Firebug) the successful processing of a script/function I want to debug.